# Identify this LEGO set: greys with two dishes

Tags: set-identification

We’ve been given a box of LEGO and are trying to determine which set these might be from (if they are a set) to try and rebuild, grateful for any help. Looking for identifiers on the pieces but not seen anything yet so help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

These part are from:

[7675: AT-TE Walker](https://brickset.com/sets/7675-1/AT-TE-Walker)
[image]

Keyparts:

- [30249 Slope 55 6 x 1 x 5](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30249#T=C)
- [32271 -Technic, Liftarm, Modified Bent Thick 1 x 9 (7 - 3)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32271&idColor=86#T=C&C=86)

in Light Bluish Gray

Comment: Brilliant thank you!

Comment: If found the answer satisfactory, keep in mind that it's considered good manners to *accept* the answer. See https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers .

Comment: I wonder if Stack Exchange could detect a comment saying "thank you" by the question poser, and prompt a conversion to an accept instead.